# What is C# equivalent to C++ Handle

Tags: c#, c++

Hi I need help to understand what is equivalent to c++ Handle in c#.
i need to call this dll and the method provided is using c++ as below

```
HANDLE hCTAPI;
hCTAPI = ctOpen(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);

if (hCTAPI == NULL)
    dwStatus = GetLastError();    // get error
else {
    ctTagWrite(hCTAPI, "SP123", "1.23");
    ctClose(hCTAPI);
}
// example of open for remote TCP/IP connection.
hCTAPI = ctOpen("203.19.130.2", "ENGINEER", "user", 0);
```

in my c# code:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\dll\CtApi.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr ctOpen(string a, string b, string c, int d);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr ptrObj = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
    ptrObj = ctOpen("192.168.1.192", "Engineer", "00", 0);  
}
```

the API should return something. When i do debugging value for ptrObj is always 0

API reference

> ctOpen(sComputer, sUser, sPassword, nMode)

Comment: `c++` doesn't build-in a `HANDLE` type, you should check the library spec.

Comment: `HANDLE` is usually *translated* to an `IntPtr` (or `HandleRef`, but it's the same), so your code could be `IntPtr ptrObj = ctOpen("192.168.1.192", "Engineer", "00", 0);`. But I'm not shure what string format it's expecting. Try changing you declaration in `[DllImport(@"C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp2\WindowsFormsApp2\dll\CtApi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]`. If it doent's work, try with `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`.

Comment: @Jimi don't forget to take `CallingConvention` into account in the `DllImport`, too. Not all APIs use `stdcall`. Check the declaration of `ctOpen()` in C++ to find out its true calling convention

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  If I got the library right, it states *To use 2015 CTAPI (...) user needs to have Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) and .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed on the machine*. So I assumed it's pretty much standard.

Comment: Thank you guys. I've solved the problem, found that API is not enabled at the scada site. tested with my original c# code and i also code using c++  and both are working

Comment: @Jimi that quote doesn't change what I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the target machine has refused your connection.

1. Try GetLastError Function to check the error.
2. Try using Process Monitor to see what your application is trying to connect to. Filter by your process name and then watch for TCP* events, you should see the destination IP and port.

P/S: As far as I can tell from the CTAPI docs the PInvoke signatures you are using are correct so this may be an issue with your CT installation/configuration.

Answer (score -2):

A HANDLE is an unsigned integer that represents a pointer to a resource.

```
uint hCTAPI = ctOpen(NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Should work for you. It gives you a pointer to the resource you instantiating in your case. The when you want to call the methods of this resource, the methods will probably require the hCTAPI to be the first (or last) argument in the signature.

Comment: No it's not, a handle is a pointer, which is absolutely not an "unsigned integer".

Comment: @bindy: A pointer as defined by the C Standard can be either a signed or unsigned integer. as per ISO; ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.5 Expressions, p7:
An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: 88)
— a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
— a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,

Comment: And in support of this take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types  Put the points back....

Comment: You quote the correct part, yet understand nothing of what you type. Let me say it again, in small words: *a pointer is not an `uint`*.